# Unlicensed VisualSVN Server on a machine belonging to a domain - will it run?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, ankhsvn

I'm going to be doing some casual development at work and wanted to just set up VisualSVN as I've used it in the past and it worked fine.

At first reading the version and licensing page, I was under the impression that it would be $79, but I now think that's just for the client.  The server says the free Standard edition is "Available for commercial use" and is free, whereas the Enterprise version is $950 per server.

Does anyone know, can I install the free server at work and buy the $79 client license and I'm compliant?

If I download either unlicensed and try to install/run will it terminate do to my machine belonging to a domain?

Is there some purely free alternative I should be using?

https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/purchase/

https://www.visualsvn.com/server/licensing/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software licenses and fees, which should be addressed to the specific vendor. It is not about programming or use of programmers tools as defined in the help guidelines.

Comment: I don't disagree, but would it be *useful knowledge* for the community?

Comment: That's irrelevant. Questions here must be on-topic according to the guidelines. If it's *useful knowledge* within those guidelines, it's appropriate. If not, it's still off-topic.

Comment: You can contact sales@visualsvn.com with the question, BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know, can I install the free server at work and buy the
>   $79 client license and I'm compliant?

Yes, you are.

Please note that [VisualSVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) and [VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/) are different products:

- VisualSVN is a plug-in for Visual Studio that integrates Subversion to the development environment. It's free to be used on a machine that's not joined a domain. On a domain machine it requires a valid license.
- VisualSVN Server is a pure Subversion server for Windows platform. It's Standard Edition is free and permits commercial use. It's Enterprise Edition is not free, but it provides a number of unique and handy features for enterprise users. Take a closer look at the feature comparison at https://www.visualsvn.com/server/licensing/

PS I agree with Ken. IMO the question is off-topic on StackOverflow. 
**You can contact sales@visualsvn.com with the question, BTW**